# Joint probability distribution discrete random variable

Tags: probability

(a) Suppose X and Y be discrete random variables with joint probability mass function given as:
 P(X = x,Y = y) =y/24x , for x = 1,2,4; y = 2,4,8;
 and x ≤ y;
 0, elsewhere 
Calculate P(X + Y 2 > 5).

Comment: There aren't that many possibilities here... you can make yourself a table with the values.  Now, find which entries in the table correspond to $X+Y^2>5$ and add the corresponding probabilities.

Comment: ooops made a mistake with the question

Comment: Its should be "Calculate P(X+Y/2>5)" instead

Comment: That doesn't change the advice in any way... Make your table... find the probability that $x=1$ and $y=2$.  Find the probability that $x=1$ and $y=4$.  Find the probability that $x=1$ and $y=8$... keep going through the rest of the possibilities... Organize the results in a table.  Identify which entries in the table correspond to the event you are interested in calculating the probability of.  Add the values from those entries in the table.

Comment: The problem can be thought of in two parts.  The first part is "*Here is an empty table, and a rule for how to fill in numbers into the table.  Fill in the numbers*"  The second part is "*Here is a rule on whether to color a number in a table red or blue.  Add up all the red numbers.*"  Both parts should be trivial.

Comment: oh okay great! Thanks, got it now

Answer (score 1):

We can observe that event $\{X+2Y=5\}$ can be rewritten as a disjoint union of events.The only events that will matter in the computation of such probability are those with strictly positive probability. For example $X=10 ,Y=-2$ satisfies $X+2Y=5$ but $P(X=10,Y=-2)=0$ so it will not matter. So in the end $$\{X+2Y=5\}=\{X=1,Y=4\} \cup \{X=1,Y=8\} \cup \{X=2,Y=2\} \cup \{X=2,Y=4\} \cup \{X=2,Y=8\} \cup \{X=4,Y=4\} \cup \{X=4,Y=8\} $$

You can easily see that for all the remaining values for $X$ and $Y$ their joint probability mass function is $0$. You conclude using this fact: the probability of a union of disjointed events is equal to the sum of their probabilities.